# Why can't I multiply the elements in my list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

I can't seem to multiply the integers in my array.

```
grid = [8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 35, 29, 76, 51, 87]

digits = 1
startPos = 0
total = []

for i in range(0,7):
    for i in range(startPos, startPos+3):
        value = int(grid[i:i+1])
        digits = digits * value
    total.append(digits)
    startPos = startPos + 1
    digits = 1
```

I keep getting the error

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

As far as I'm aware the values in my array ARE integers. What have I done wrong? For clarification, I'm searching for the biggest value that can be made from any 3 adjacent numbers in the array.

Comment: You can't give an array as argument to `int`. Try putting `int(grid[i])` instead of `int(grid[i:i+1])`

Comment: `grid[i:i+1]` gets a slice not an element. `[1,2,3,4][1:2] -> [2]`

Answer (score 2):

The `grid[i:i+1]` will give you a list and you can not pass a list to `int` function, instead of that you can simply use `i` as the index to get the element :

```
int(grid[i])
```

If you wan't to apply an `int` function to a list of elements you can use `map` :

```
map(int,my_list)
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham He, I see! :) I think OP meant that they are digit string (I hope it will be like that ;) )

Comment: I think they just got confused between indexing and slicing.  once the code is changed to `int(grid[i])` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:
`value = grid[i:i+1][0]`
instead of `value = int(grid[i:i+1])`
becouse `grid[i:i+1]` is a list of len 1.

```
for i in range(0,7):
    for i in range(startPos, startPos+3):
        print(i,i+1,grid[i:i+1], grid[i:i+1][0])

0 1 [8] 8  
1 2 [2] 2  
2 3 [22] 22  
1 2 [2] 2  
...
```